# text-file to linked-list C

Tags: c, file, linked-list, text-files

So im trying to save a text file in a linked-list (each node containing a word) and that's my code so far. It just wont even run no matter what i do. please help if you can.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define W 30000
#define M 35
typedef struct node {
    char * str;
    struct node * node ;
} Node;
typedef Node * ListofChar;
typedef Node * CharNode_ptr;
Node * createnode(char text[M]);
void letters(ListofChar * lst_ptr);

int main(void){
    ListofChar chars = NULL;
    letters(&chars);
    return 0;
    }

Node * createnode(char text[M]){
    CharNode_ptr newnode_ptr ;
    newnode_ptr = malloc(sizeof (Node));
    strcpy(newnode_ptr->str, text);
    printf("%s\n", newnode_ptr->str);
    newnode_ptr -> node = NULL;
    return newnode_ptr;
    }
void letters(ListofChar * lst_ptr){
    FILE *file;
    char txt[M];
    Node *ptr;
    ptr=*lst_ptr;
    file=fopen("Notebook.txt","r");
    while ((fscanf(file,"%29s",txt) != EOF)){
        if (strcmp(txt,"*")){
            (*lst_ptr)=createnode(txt);
            (*lst_ptr)->node=ptr;
            ptr=*lst_ptr;}}
    fclose(file);
    return;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "won't even run"? Your program won't compile, or doesn't produce the correct result?

Comment: Is you compiler giving you [this list](https://godbolt.org/z/7TcxoEnYG) of errors and warnings? Is there one of those you don't understand? (you are missing some `#include`s)

Comment: It seems very strange that M is 35, but you are using the format string `%29s`.  This will work, but hard-coding the format string means that future changes which may modify M to be less than 30 will be a breaking change.  Either 1) ignore the problem and hope it's not an issue 2) build the format string dynamically 3) do pre-processor magic to compute M-1 and build the format string at compile time, or (best choice!) stop using scanf and read the data with getchar.

Comment: You never initialize `newnode_ptr->str` so `strcpy(newnode_ptr->str, text);` is UB.

Comment: <O/T> it's bad practice to hide pointers behind `typedef`s

Comment: the posted code does not compile!   are you wanting us to fix the compile problems or do you want help with something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `createnode`, you have the lines:

```
newnode_ptr = malloc(sizeof (Node));
strcpy(newnode_ptr->str, text);
```

Since `newnode_ptr->str` is never initialized, this is undefined behavior.  Try:

```
newnode_ptr = xmalloc(sizeof *newnode_ptr);
newnode_ptr->str = xstrdup(text);
```

where `xmalloc` and `xstrdup` are the obvious wrappers around `malloc` and `strdup` that abort on failure.